# Using Null in a DLookup Criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am creating a database to manage the flow of people in and out of an incident system. My idea is to use the DLookup function to allow me to identify a null value in the checkout date. This would allow me to prevent someone from jumping incidents without signing out first.

If it is possible I would like to get the EVENT ID and the COMMAND POST ID so I can create an error message to tell me the incident that is member is still attached to.

```
'***Section 1 - Ensure member is Checked out and DEMOBed from previous incidents
'******Variables
'*********Variable to hold the Member ID
Dim id As Integer
'*********Variable to hold the checkout status
Dim checkout As String
'*********Variable to hold the Event ID
Dim eventID As Integer


'******Code Block 1 - Check for Null Values
id = Me.Text18
Forms![frm_ics238Table].Refresh

If Not IsNull(DLookup("[eventID]", "[frm_ics238Table]", "[checkoutDate] is Null And employeeID = '" & Me.Text18 & "'")) Then
    MsgBox "y"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `"{frm_ics238Table]"` to `"[frm_ics238Table]"`

Comment: @dbmitch Thank you for the catch. I have been stairing at this for pretty much the entire day. changed it over and get Run-Time Error '6': Overflow

Comment: You don't have an ending bracket around your `DLookup` function either. Perhaps you should split out individual logic and get each one working first before building the whole statement at once

Comment: @dbmitch I am pretty sure there is a ending bracket there are two (( at the beginning and two )) at the end. I cant see any others

Comment: Ahhh - I see you're using multiple criteria. Try using `IsNull([checkoutDate])` instead and  making sure Text18 is showing a value

Comment: Stupid question but I'm assuming `frm_ics238Table` is actually a table name - you're using it as a Form name above?

Comment: @dbmitch I tried it out and the DLookup errors out. DLookup("[eventID]", "[tbl_ics238Table]", isNull([checkoutDate])). Yes that's supposed to be the table but I accidentally changed it to the form name

Comment: Why don't you post your updated code and error above - now it looks like you've left out the double quotes on the criteria. Two errors have been corrected already in your one question

Answer (score 1):

From your original question which right now it doesn't look like you've edited it to indicate the updated code and errors, you had:

```
id = Me.Text18
Forms![frm_ics238Table].Refresh

If Not IsNull(DLookup("[eventID]", "[frm_ics238Table]", "[checkoutDate] is Null And employeeID = '" & Me.Text18 & "'")) Then
    MsgBox "y"
End If
```

I think these might help:

1. `"[frm_ics238Table]"` should be table:`"[tbl_ics238Table]"`
2. ID appears to be declared as an integer yet you're using it as a
   string. If employeeID is actually a numeric field remove the quotes
   around `employeeID = '" & Me.Text18 & "'"` It should look like this `employeeID = " & ID & "`
3. You can also try using `IsNull([checkoutDate])` instead of
   `[checkoutDate] is Null`

SO it might look like:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("[eventID]", "[tbl_ics238Table]", "IsNull([checkoutDate]) And (employeeID = " & ID & ")")) Then
    MsgBox "y"
End If
```

Even better would be to put the criteria into a string variable so you could debug and test it first

```
Dim strCriteria as String
strCriteria = "IsNull([checkoutDate]) And (employeeID = " & ID & ")"
Debug.Print strCriteria

If Not IsNull(DLookup("[eventID]", "[tbl_ics238Table]", strCriteria)) Then
    MsgBox "y"
End If
```

**EDIT: PROOF OF WORKING CODE:**

Not that I don't believe you but I don't believe that it doesn't work if what you've described matches my assumptions.

I tested successfully using assumptions that:

- eventID - number field
- checkoutDate - date/time field
- employeeID - number field

**My sample data table**

[image: table]

Then I put a command button on a form to test the code:

```
Private Sub Command8_Click()
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim ID As Integer

    ID = 4

    strCriteria = "IsNull([checkoutDate]) And (employeeID = " & ID & ")"
    Debug.Print strCriteria

    If Not IsNull(DLookup("[eventID]", "[tbl_ics238Table]", strCriteria)) Then
        MsgBox "y"
    End If

End Sub
```

Finally - testing the button click resulted in:

[image: Results]

> In conclusion - if you're still getting an error then you can update
>   your question with BOTH your code AND your table design.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance and I tried what you suggested but it just gives me a run-time error code 2471. I will keep working on it. It looks like using the is null function isn't really feasible for DLookup

Comment: I edited the question to show that it does indeed work if code matches table design assumptions. To this point I haven't seen ANY of your code updates.